# af:query - view with bind var

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm using af:query on a view with bind var.
this bind var displayed as one of the search fields.
I don't want to let the user to change the value of the bind var.
how could I hide this field?
It is not an attribute so I can't do that with uncheck the 'Quaryable' checkbox.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the bind variable and edit it (Query Tab in VO editor) there is a Control Hints tab. Try changing Display Hint from "Display" to "Hide."